# Proving measurable function: Real versus rational number

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am working on this problem$^{(1)}$ on measurable function like this:

> Show that $f$ is measurable if $(X, \mathcal A)$ is measurable space, $f$ is real-value function and $\{x \mid f(x) > r \} \in \mathcal A$ for each rational number $r.$

Earlier on the text gives this definition$^{{2}}$ of measurable function:

> A function $f : X \to \mathbb R$ is *measurable* or $\mathcal A$-*measurable* if $\{x \mid f(x) > a \} \in \mathcal A$ for all $a \in \mathbb R.$

To an untrained eyes, the problem with this problem is that there seems to be no problem at all, except, perhaps, that the exercise says "$\forall r \in \mathbb Q$", whereas the definition says "$\forall a \in \mathbb R.$" Am I on the right track here? Please help me going forward if this is the right issue to tackle.

Thank you for your time and help.

---

Footnotes: 
(1) Richard F. Bass' [*Real Analysis*](http://homepages.uconn.edu/~rib02005/real-analysis-04nov2011.pdf), 2nd. edition, chapter 5: Measurable Functions, Exercise 5.1, page 44. 
(2) Definition 5.1, page 37.

Comment: Based on the "weaker" $\forall x\in\mathbb{Q}\left[\dots\right]$ you must prove the "stronger"
$\forall x\in\mathbb{R}\left[\dots\right]$ so yes: there is a problem here.

Comment: Bingo, you are on the right path. All you have to prove is that $\{x \mid f(x) > a \} \in \mathcal A$ even for all irrational $a$.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I up-arrowed both of your since they are important. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exercise is assuming that $\{x : f(x) > r\} \in \mathcal A$ for each rational $r$.

You now need to show that it holds for all $a \in \mathbb R$, not just the rationals, for it to satisfy the definition of measurable function.

You are on the right track.

As another exercise for you: this can be generalized slightly to the following, without much change to the proof:

> Let $A$ be a dense subset of $\mathbb R$. Then $f$ is measurable if $\{x : f(x) > a\}$ is measurable for all $a \in A$.

---

As an update to your comment, I think the theorem itself you mentioned doesn't help directly, but the proof teaches you the technique you should use in this case.

Pick $a \in \mathbb R$, since $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$, find a sequence $\{q_k\}$ in $\mathbb Q$ such that $\displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty} q_k = a$ (from above), then notice that $$\{x : f(x) > a\}  = \bigcup \{x : f(x) > q_k\}.$$

Comment: Thanks as always. So, since $\mathbb Q \subset \mathbb R$, therefore I need to focus on only those in $\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$? Am I narrowing it down correctly? Thanks again.

Comment: If you could click on the online book link I provided above, go to Proposition 5.5, on page 38, I have a "sneaky" feeling that it might be useful, but my feeling is sometime unreliable. What do you think? Thanks again!

Comment: I think you meant $q_k$ and not $q_n$. One question: Can you explain in plain English what does it mean by $\lim_{k \to \infty} q_k$ = a? To me, it looks like that it means that "Give me any number $a \in \mathbb R$. Even if it is irrational, but if you are willing to go to infinity, you can always find a rational number $q \in \mathbb Q$ such that $r = q$." I am sure it's wrong, but not sure where the wrong is. Let me know and thanks again.

Comment: You can always approach an irrational number via a sequence of rational numbers. This follows from the fact that $\mathbb Q$ are dense in $\mathbb R$. For instance, take $\pi \in \mathbb R$, we can consider the sequence $3, 3.1, 3.14, 3.141, 3.1415, \ldots$; the sequence converges to $\pi$, but no element in the sequence will ever be $\pi$! The irrational number will **never** be equal to a rational, but we can pick a rational number arbitrarily close to it!

Comment: Ok, thanks. I got to the last line you left off, that is, $\{x : f(x) > a\}  = \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} \{x : f(x) > q_k\}.$ How do you go from that to conclude that $f$ is measurable function? Thanks again.

Comment: Each $q_k$ is rational! and by hypothesis $\{x : f(x) > r\} \in \mathcal A$ is measurable for $r$ rational. A union of measurable sets is measurable.

Comment: Robert, I homespun my own folksy solution mainly based on yours, see my answer below. Could you please look at (5)? I wanted to know if I used the right language in this paragraph (5) and if I jumped too far to a conclusion. Thanks again and again.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

For $a\in\mathbb R$ let $(r_n)_n$ be a decreasing sequence in $\mathbb Q$ converging to $a$.

Try to express $\{x\mid f(x)>a\}$ in the sets $\{x\mid f(x)>r_n\}$.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at that. In the meantime, if you click on the online book link I provided above, go to Proposition 5.5, on page 38, I have a "sneaky" feeling that it might be useful, but my feeling is unreliable. What do you think? Thanks again!

Comment: That proposition only tells us that by definition we can actually choose between $\geq a$, $>a$, $\leq a$ or $<a$. It is not relevant when it comes to the problem mentioned in your question.

Comment: Well said, well done -- you are good and helpful member of this wonderful community. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I am posting this solution that was spun out of solutions from @RobertCardona and @drhab , thanks to both of you for patiently fielding my clueless-at-best, dumb-at-worst questions.

(1) Let $a \in \mathbb R$ such that $\{x \mid f(x) > a \} \in \mathcal A$. Thus $f(x)$ is a measurable function.

(2) $\forall a \in \mathbb R$, there exists a sequence {$r_k$}, $r_k \in \mathbb Q$ and $k \in \mathbb N$, such that $r_k$ converges to $a$. That is,

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} r_k = a.$$

(3) Observe that $\{x \mid f(x) > a \}$ can be expressed in term of many, many $ \{x \mid f(x) > r_k\}$. Thus,

$$\{x \mid f(x) > a \} = \bigcup _{k=1}^{\infty} \{x \mid f(x) > r_k\}.$$

(4) Recall that $\{x \mid f(x) > r_k\} \in \mathcal A$ by hypothesis. Since union of measurable sets is also measurable, therefore

$$\bigcup _{k=1}^{\infty} \{x \mid f(x) > r_k\} \in \mathcal A,$$

where $r_k$ is rational number.

(5) Since the $f(x)$ in the RHS of equation (3) is a measurable function, thus it's  implied that the $f(x)$ in the LHS is also measurable function for $r \in \mathbb Q.$ $\qquad \blacksquare$

Comment: For (1), I'm not sure what you're trying to say. If you're stating the hypothesis, it should be something like: "Suppose $\{x : f(x) > r\} \in \mathcal A$ for all $r$ rational", if you're trying to state the definition of measurable function, say "$f$ is measurable if $\{x : f(x) > a\} \in \mathcal A$ for all $a \in \mathbb R$".

Comment: For (2), you don't just want a sequence, you want a sequence that converges from above. This is necessary to show the equality in (3), which I would say you need a bit more work to show! (Try a double containment proof); (4) looks good; (5) you say "$f(x)$ on the RHS" and "$f(x)$ on the LHS", but you don't have $f(x)$ in those equations, you have sets of the form $\{x : f(x) > r\}$, so I would just say "RHS", "LHS" instead.

Comment: @RobertCardona : Never, never stop loving your explanation, I will put in your suggestions to mine. One curious, side question - if you please: How did you get alerted of my incoming comment so fast? I got alerted by MSE always one or two days late, did MSE endow you with special privilege because of your knowledge? :-) Thanks again and again.

Comment: No, it's always a day or two late for me too, but since you green-checked my answer, that alert was immediate, so I came here and saw the comment too.